# Why the static member of the Test class in c++ is breaking encapsulation rules?

Tags: static, encapsulation

In the following code i have declared a test class and a static member of same type (t1) but how its data members are accessible by . operator

```
class Test{
    int a;
    static Test t1;
    public:
    explicit Test(int);
    explicit Test();
    static void set_test();
    void init();
    void print();
};
```

```
Test::Test():a(t1.a){}
Test::Test(int value):a(value){}
Test Test::t1(1);
void Test::init(){
    a=t1.a;
}
void Test::print(){
    cout<<a;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.print();
    return 0;
}
```